# Adding action to map in QGIS when link to actions menu item is missing?

Tags: qgis-3, hyperlink, actions

I am running qgis 3.8.0 zanzibar on ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to set a hyper link on a point on the sample map (Alaska).

A casual perusal tells me that I should set up an action. https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-and-hyperlinks. There is supposed to be a gear button. I don't find one.

Then at this point on stack exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/actions/info there is a link to help on setting up actions.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html?highlight=actions

The help link is broken.

Comment: The final help link you have is for a very old version of the QGIS training manual. Recent documentation is available at qgis.org.